# What is this pattern called? Soft Lock?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, naming

Here is a bit of code that I have to write sometimes, mostly in conjunction with UI stuff, and always with events that can accidentally wind up in infinite loops.

```
  public class MyClass
  {
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;
    private bool IsHandlingEvent = false;

    public MyClass()
    {
      MyEvent += new EventHandler(MyClass_MyEvent);
    }

    void MyClass_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (IsHandlingEvent) { return; }

      IsHandlingEvent = true;
      {
        // Code goes here that handles the event, possibly invoking 'MyEvent' again.
        // IsHandlingEvent flag is used to avoid redundant processing.  What is this
        // technique, or pattern called.
        // ...
      }
      IsHandlingEvent = false;
    }
  }
```

As you can see, using the flag 'IsHandlingEvent' is used to prevent redundant, or possible endless event invocations.  While I don't always do stuff like this (because of obvious dangers), sometimes it is a useful solution, but I don't know what to call it.  For lack of a better term, I have been using "soft lock".  What is the real name?

**EDIT:**
Yes, I know that it isn't threadsafe, etc.  This is a name question, not a design question.  But since it is worth discussing...
[Code improvement: Better alternatives to this pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259939/code-improvement-better-alternatives-to-this-pattern)

Comment: Note that this code isn't threadsafe. There could be a context switch immediately after one thread tests `IsEventHandling`. However, if it's UI related, then it's likely fine, since it's the UI thread that will be raising events.

Comment: Nor is it exception-safe. So I think this pattern should be called "DontUse" :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the part about the event invoking 'MyEvent' again is called "Programmer Screwed Up" ...

Comment: @Corey: would be exception-safe if `catch(Exception e) { IsHandlingEvent = false; }`

Comment: I was about to say the same thing @dlev, but this is just a bad example, but a good question. I removed the code to the relevant species so not to distract to the actual question

Comment: @dlev it will also behave incorrectly if it is re-entrant on a single thread; a counter might work better

Comment: @Marc Good point. As hard as thread-safety is to get right, reentrancy is *even harder*.

Comment: Is the question even the same now after those edits?  The code has changed a lot.

Comment: @Chris Lively This can easily happen, for example if you have a OnCheckChanged call for a CheckBox that may change the state of the CheckBox would need this pattern.

Comment: Looking better after your edit. I might propose using Interlocked.Exchange to set and clear the IsHandling variable (then you won't need the lock()), and then wrap the whole thing in a little utility method: DoThisActionOrDoNothing(ref IsHandlingEvent, ()=>code goes here that handles the event)

Comment: @Marc Gravell, I think he is specifically trying to prevent this code from being reentrant. `As you can see, using the flag 'IsHandlingEvent' is used to prevent redundant, or possible endless event invocations.`

Comment: Rolled back to 1st version. If you want to suggest a better implementation, answer the question, do not edit the OP's code, as the question, the comments and the other answers wouldn't make sense anymore.

Comment: @Everyone, I asked a new question that addresses the issue of how to make the code better + what is the best option.  Link is in this question.

Comment: Sometimes it's a necessary precaution when changes can trigger events that can trigger changes.  If it's single-threaded protect it with a try...finally, if it's multi-threaded protect it with a lock.

Answer (score 3):

There is already alot said about the design (being not thread-safe etc.).

You seem to ask for a name... don't know if this widespread but I heard it several times referered to as a reentrancy sentinel.

Comment: Thanks for sticking to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is somewhat related to a [Semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29), i.e.: looking access to something with a boolean variable.

Edit: As pointed in the question's comment, this "pattern" should be avoided due to not being threadsafe, exception-safe and good.

Comment: I wouldn't think it's anything like a Semaphore personally.  One is an actual synchronization primitive, the other is just booleans and prayers.

Comment: I didn't say it **is** a semaphore - the primitive one - but it's what is the more looking alike.

Comment: I know you didn't say it was a semaphore, I just don't think it even resembles one in usage.

Comment: @Adam: why do think that (real curiosity)

Comment: Well I suppose the original version of the code could look structurally similar with respect to incrementing the decrementing the resource count.  As an answer I just thought the semaphore reference was a little tenuous, and a semaphore isn't technically a pattern.

Comment: A semaphore holds the execution off until it's ok to proceed - just like a lock. The execution of a protected section is supposed to happen eventually. This solution simply drops the event on the floor instead and pretends nothing happened.