# Code improvement: Better alternatives to this pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In a similar question:
[What is this pattern called? Soft Lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259436/what-is-this-pattern-called-soft-lock)

I was asking about the name of the pattern for the code listing below.

```
  public class MyClass
  {
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;
    private bool IsHandlingEvent = false;

    public MyClass()
    {
      MyEvent += new EventHandler(MyClass_MyEvent);
    }

    void MyClass_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (IsHandlingEvent) { return; }

      IsHandlingEvent = true;
      {
        // Code goes here that handles the event, possibly invoking 'MyEvent' again.
        // IsHandlingEvent flag is used to avoid redundant processing.  What is this
        // technique, or pattern called.
        // ...
      }
      IsHandlingEvent = false;
    }
  }
```

It seems that most of the conversation was centered around why we should an should not do this, so I think that this question provides a better forum to tackle the problem and address all of the issues.  What is the better / proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

There are series of problems with that pattern. If you want to invoke the handler only once, you would do something like this:

```
 protected static object _lockObj = new object();
 protected static bool _isHandled = false;    

 void MyClass_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if(_isHandled)
       return;

     lock(_lockObj)
     {
         if(_isHandled)
            return;

         _isHandled = true;

         MyOtherPossiblyRecursiveMethod(); // Actually does all your work

         _isHandled = false;
     }
 }

 void MyOtherPossiblyRecursiveMethod()
 {
 }
```

This way, only one thread should be able to access the actual work method.

Comment: Are you sure the lock will works if re-rais happens on the same thread ( that is the scenario discussed by A.R. ) ?

Comment: You might also want to make `_isHandled` volatile. Or, even better, avoid double-checked-locking altogether and only check `_isHandled` inside the `lock` block.

Comment: @LukeH If you check the _isHandled state inside `lock` block then sometimes the calling thread will be frozen until `MyOtherPossiblyRecursiveMethod()` finishes and the block is unlocked. It's better to check twice here.

Comment: @Artemix: Maybe, maybe not. But in that case if you don't mark `_isHandled` as volatile then it's (theoretically) possible for a thread to read a stale version of `_isHandled` and never enter the `lock` block even when it should.

Answer (score 1):

I will use something like:

```
using( var sl = new SoftLock() )
{
   sl.Execute(()=>{....});
}
```

the execute will raise the internal boolean to prevent re-entering. In the dispose that flag would be resetted. Execute will call the lambda just if the flag is false. This is to ensure flag go to false even if exception happens ( causing handler never executed ) and maybe is a little better to see. Of course this is not thread safe, as the original code, but this because we are talking about preventing double execution from the *same* thread.

Answer (score 1):

The original code is a sufficient (and very lightweight) way to prevent recursion in a single-threaded app. So if during your event handling function you could get into code that might be firing the event again you will not enter infinite recursion.

But the code is not sufficient to prevent access from multiple threads, due to the potential for race conditions. If you need to ensure only one thread gets to run this event, then you should use a stronger locking mechanism, like a Mutex or Semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in single- and multi-threaded scenarios and is exception-safe... also if need be it can be modified to allow for a certain level of reentrancy (for example 3 levels)...

```
public class MyClass
{
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
private int IsHandlingEvent = 0;

public MyClass()
{
  MyEvent += new EventHandler(MyClass_MyEvent);
}

void MyClass_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // this allows for nesting if needed by comparing for example < 3 or similar
 if (Interlocked.Increment (ref IsHandlingEvent) == 1 )
 {
  try {
      }
  finally {};  
 } 

 Interlocked.Decrement (ref IsHandlingEvent);
}
}
```

Comment: again, if we are on the same thread Interlocked does not have anything to interlock...

Comment: not sure what problem you see... this code is just meant to work with single and multi-thread-scenario... if the OP usually works with single threads it won't hurt at all and it would achieve what he want... as a "bonus" he can keep the code the same when moving to a multi-threaded design... another bonus is that is exception-safe...